# Maximal subgroup and representations (dual part)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $V$ an irreducible complex representation, $H$ a subgroup.
Let $V^H$ be the subspace of vectors of $V$ invariant under the action of $H$.

Let $g \in G$, $K = H \cap g^{-1}Hg$ and $W$ an irreducible complex representation of $H$.

> **Question**: Is $dim(W^K) \le 1$ if $H$ is a **maximal** subgroup of $G$ ?

**Remark** : If $H = \{ e \}$ then $G = \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $dim(W)=1$.

Comment: If G is a Frobenius group with nonabelian complement H then K =1 W of dim >= 2 is counterexample.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: by assumption $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. Do you know an example of Frobenius group $G$ whose Frobenius complement $H$ is nonabelian and maximal ?

Comment: Frobenius example given too

Comment: For poeple in subfactor theory: this *dual* post is confusing because $\mathcal{P}_{2,-}(R^G \subset R^H)$ is always abelian... This dual part asks about the multiplicity of the depth $2$-$3$ edges of the dual principal graph of $(R^G \subset R^H)$, whereas the principal post is about the multiplicity of the depth $1$-$2$ edges of the principal graph (see [Jones-Sunder](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/introduction-subfactors) p141).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest $G$ in a counterexample is $G=A_5$ with $H=\langle (1,2)(4,5), (1,2,3) \rangle \cong S_3$ and $g=(3,4,5)$ and $K=H \cap H^g = 1$. Take $W$ to be the unique irreducible complex representation of $H$ with dimension greater than 1 to get $W^K = W$ as counterexample.

The second smallest $G$ in a counterexample is the Frobenius group $G= Q_8 \ltimes (C_3 \times C_3)$ with $H=Q_8$ non-abelian and maximal. Again $K=1$ so $W$ is any irreducible non-linear representation of $H$.

Comment: Thank you ! Are these counter-examples also counter-examples for the [principal part](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684172/maximal-subgroup-and-representations-principal-part) ?  Else do you have an idea about the [principal part](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684172/maximal-subgroup-and-representations-principal-part)  ?

Comment: The principal part was harder to find counterexamples since counterexamples will be more plentiful if the index of H in G is very large. Hence checking in order of $|G|$ or $[G:H]$ is not wise. Instead I checked character tables of simple groups, which worked well (though it took me a while to realize that would work well).